# RabbitMQ messages being published twice with PHP AMQP Lib and Docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I've setup a local instance of RabbitMQ using Docker Compose and am going through the hello world example on the RabbitMQ docs. Here is a simple attempt at connecting, creating a queue and pushing a message to it:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$rabbitMqHost = 'rabbitmq';

if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
    $rabbitMqHost = '0.0.0.0';
}

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($rabbitMqHost, 5672, 'guest', 'guest');

$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);

$message = new AMQPMessage('Hello, world!' . microtime(true));

$channel->basic_publish($message, '', 'hello');

echo '[x] Sent \'Hello, world!\'';

$channel->close();
$connection->close();

exit;
```

This connects fine and creates the queue if it doesn't exist and when this script is ran in the command line, 1 message is added to the queue as expected. However, if I access this script in my browser, 2 new items are added to the queue.

```
Payload: Hello, world!1666282109.6845
Payload: Hello, world!1666282109.8559
```

I now feel like this issue is further upstream and may be related more to my Nginx setup, however I'm not sure what is causing this and the page doesn't seem to perform any redirects.

Here is the contents of my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECTDIR}:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  php:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECTDIR}:/var/www/html
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: docker
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ./rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
```

And my Dockerfiles for `php-fpm` and `nginx` respectively:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
```

```
FROM nginx:1.23-alpine

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

EXPOSE 80 443
```

Finally, my `nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+`.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
}
```

I'd be really grateful for any insights as to why this is always putting two messages into the queue when accessed via a browser?

For reference, the environment config can also be seen in the [GitHub repo on the rabbitmq branch](https://github.com/DanielWinning/php-environment/tree/rabbitmq).

Comment: (Upvote for a perfect minimal code sample!) Reproduced locally, and only one message appeared in queue. Mgmt shows "Ready 1; Total 1" which is what I'd expect. (And they increment by one each run). Q1) do you "get" two messages if you pull, or just one? Also check they are the same message by adding `microtime(true)` to the end of the message you publish.

Comment: @Robbie thanks very much for your time and your comment, I posted this quite late and have had work today so sorry if I've appeared ignorant. I've figured out that when I run this in my command line, only 1 item is added to the queue - two separate items are added to the queue displaying different microtime values when accessed in the browser, so I feel this is most likely due to my environment setup - I've added some more details now to the question but unfortunately now it's much more verbose and likely less reproducible

Comment: Just wondering, what does the SQL DB and the web server do there? Do they make a difference? How exactly do you run the PHP code?

Comment: Could it be you have another Docker image running, maybe an earlier attempt? If you change this code (eg add some text to this), do both messages appear changed?

Comment: @Martijn this was my initial thought, so I ran through some Docker troubleshooting steps - destroying all my images, exiting/restarting Docker, system reboot after removing images etc.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt in this instance the SQL DB isn't really relevant - I run this using docker compose to build the container, updating `PROJECTDIR` in my `.env` file to the path to my project (in this case `/Users/danny/Development/rabbit-test` / `/c/Development/rabbit-test` - then my project code just contains: `/vendor`, `composer.json` and `index.php`. My issue here was that I was just sticking this code in `index.php` and hitting `http://localhost` to run it in my browser - the accepted answer is the solution to the problem in my case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In browser, check "Developer Tools", "Network". You'll find your browser is making two queries, probably "favicon" and the index page.

As favicon does not exist, you have that redirecting to index.php - that will trigger the second rabbit message you are seeing.

Solution: add a favicon, redirect to another "missing file handler" or check the query string. Or rename the test file as "test.php" and remove the rabbit code from index.php.

Comment: Thank you! It was looking for the favicon that was causing the problem - I was checking the network tab and just ignoring the request for the favicon as it seemed irrelevant - rookie move. Thanks again, this has solved my problem and it's nice to know I don't know to overhaul my dev environment so really appreciate the help on this!